# GraphQL and Sequelize doesn't return inserted object

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js, graphql

I'm stuck on an error on my `GraphQL` and `Sequelize` backend, for some reason my mutation doesn't return the data, even though I guarantee there's data being returned inside my resolver. I feel like this is probably something small that I'm missing, but I've been stuck for awhile.

The `Sequelize` part works, the object is indeed inserted, however the return is always a null object.

Here's my mutation:

```
mutation {
  createUserVoucher(pinId: 1, voucherId: 1) {
    id
  }
}
```

Here's the return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUserVoucher": {
      "id": null
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my resolver:

```
createUserVoucher: (parent, args, { user, models }) => {
  args['userId'] = user.id;
  models.UserVoucher.count({
    where: {utilized: true, pinId: args.pinId, userId: args.userId}
  }).then( c => {
    if (c > 0) {
      return []
    } else {
      models.Voucher.findOne({
        where: {
          id: args.voucherId
        }
      }).then( voucher => {
        models.UserVoucher.count({
          where: { voucherId: args.voucherId }
        }).then( c => {
            return models.UserVoucher.create(args)
        })
      })
    }
  });
  return []
}
```

UserVoucher definition:

```
type UserVoucher {
  id: Int
  nodeId: Int!
  userId: ID!
  voucherId: ID!
  voucher: Voucher
  pinId: ID!
  capturedAt: DateTime
  utilized: Boolean
}
`;
```

Mutation definition:

```
createUserVoucher(
  pinId: Int!, 
  voucherId: Int!
): UserVoucher
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing? It will be much appreciated, thank you very much!!
Also if any more information is needed, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing three returns:

```
createUserVoucher: (parent, args, { user, models }) => {
  args['userId'] = user.id;
  return models.UserVoucher.count({ <----- HERE
    where: {utilized: true, pinId: args.pinId, userId: args.userId}
  }).then( c => {
    if (c > 0) {
      return []
    } else {
      return models.Voucher.findOne({ // <----- HERE
        where: {
          id: args.voucherId
        }
      }).then( voucher => {
        return models.UserVoucher.count({ // <----- AND HERE
          where: { voucherId: args.voucherId }
        }).then( c => {
            return models.UserVoucher.create(args)
        })
      })
    }
  });
  return []
}
```

When chaining promises, it's important to remember to always return any additional promises inside each `then` call -- otherwise the promise is fired but it's not awaited.

Couple of additional notes:

While strictly not hurting anything, you should return `null` instead of an empty array inside your resolver. According to your schema, your mutation returns a nullable UserVoucher object. Returning an empty array is misleading to anyone reading your code because it implies this resolver should be returning a array.

The results from the second `UserVoucher.count` call and the `Voucher.findOne` call aren't used, which means they might not be necessary?

Lastly, you can also significantly clean up your code by using async/await:

```
createUserVoucher: async (parent, args, { user, models }) => {
  args['userId'] = user.id;
  const c = await models.UserVoucher.count({
    where: {utilized: true, pinId: args.pinId, userId: args.userId}
  })
  if (c > 0) return null
  const voucher = await models.Voucher.findOne({
    where: { id: args.voucherId }
  })
  const c2 = await models.UserVoucher.count({ 
    where: { voucherId: args.voucherId }
  })
  return models.UserVoucher.create(args) // still need a return here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had my sight on the GraphQL part but the good old promises were the problem. You're the man!